# Query friends list of facebook user using the service

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

From my understanding Facebook has made changes to their API such that third-party services can no longer have access to the friend list (at least names) of someone using your app (while being logged in facebook, of course).

Does anyone know if I maybe just missed one API endpoint, and it is still somehow possible? I just know that the original one is deprecated/has been removed. Thank you.

(Wasn't sure where to ask this, so I turned to stackoverflow. I know it's not the best use of the site, I apologize for that.)

Answer (score 1):

No, you did not miss anything, accessing the friend list is no longer possible. You can only get data of users who authorized your App too, every other user is not available at all - for privacy reasons.